# Java: JPanel Rectangle issue?

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a program that change color of the rectangle when user mouse pressed and then again
pressed default color happen i draw this on jpanel with the
help of paint component method.And i used a mouse adapter to write the mouse pressed method.But how to make a 
function that change color of rectangle to red when user mouse pressed on rectangle also appear default color when again pressed on this.This is picture
[image]
Code:

```
    public class A extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponents(g);

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(6, 10, 66, 70);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){


            }
            });
            }
    }
```

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame obj = new JFrame();
        A object = new A();
        obj.add(object);

        obj.setSize(450, 400);
        obj.setResizable(false);
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        obj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        obj.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: That looks so wrong? Why are you adding mouseListener inside paintComponent?

Comment: @Gosu because rectangle draw on paintComponent if i'm wrong then where add MouseListener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding to Gosu's answer:

If you want the color to switch only when the rectangle is clicked, you only need to add an `if` statement inside the `MouseListener`.

```
    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

             // Check if the point where the mouse was clicked is contained
             // within the drawing Rectangle.                          
             if (new Rectangle(6, 10, 66, 70).contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    object.switchColor();
                    object.revalidate();
                    object.repaint();
             }
         }
    });
```

However, keep in mind that in a realistic application, you should never hardcode anything like the rectangle in this example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final A object = new A();
        frame.add(object);

        frame.setSize(450, 400);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                object.switchColor();
                //object.revalidate();
                object.repaint();
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class A extends JPanel {

    private Color currColor = Color.BLACK;

    public void switchColor() {
        currColor = (currColor == Color.BLACK) ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);

        g.setColor(currColor);
        g.fillRect(6, 10, 66, 70);
    }
}
```

The rectangle will switch between Black and Red whenever you click inside the frame.

Comment: but it's happening on everywhere when click on frame

Comment: @hamel123 It's just listening for mouse clicks, so you want the color change to happen only when clicking on the rectangle itself?

Comment: when click on the rectangle then change color not on full frame clicks

Comment: can you suggest me what to do?

Comment: You're not changing the layout, no need to call revalidate

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, kinda assumed revalidate goes together with repaint, seen them tgt almost all the time

Answer (score 2):

You need another JPanel (or something similiar) for the square that must change color. Otherwise you will not be able to register what mouse events happen inside the square and which happen outside.
The following is a small working example.

```
public class A extends JPanel {
    private Color currColor = Color.BLACK;
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        p.setSize(new Dimension(66,70));
        p.setLocation(6, 10);
        p.setBackground(currColor);

        p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                switchColor();
                p.revalidate();
                p.repaint();
            }
        });
        add(p);
    }

    public void switchColor() {
        currColor = (currColor == Color.BLACK) ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        A t = new A();
        frame.add(t);
        frame.setSize(450,400);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```